# Multiple sort/filter factors on a Fusion tables query

Tags: sql, google-fusion-tables

I want to perform a query on my Google Fusion Table. Let's assume I am assembling the string with the below variables. Everything works fine if I have only one parameter in `var sort_factors`. How can I add a second parameter to `sort_factors` so that I can both (for example) order by date descending AND limit the response to 1000 rows?

```
var base         = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?',
    columns      = 'sql=SELECT+Lat,Lng,Date,Username,TripID',
    from         = '+from+XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    sort_factors = '+LIMIT+1000+AND+ORDER+BY+Date+DESC',
    key          = '&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` isn't a sorting, the `AND` is wrong there and the LIMIT has to be the last clause in the SQL:

```
'+ORDER+BY+Date+DESC+LIMIT+1000'
```

The order of the clauses is fixed and has to be:

1. where
2. group
3. order
4. limit

Your code seems to be Javascript, you better do yourself a favour and let JS handle the encoding.

Possible approach:

```js
var base = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query',
  columns = 'SELECT Lat,Lng,Date,Username,TripID',
  from = 'from fusionTableID',
  //apply a filter when you want to
  where = '',
  //group the results when you want to
  groupby = '',
  orderby = 'ORDER BY DATE DESC',
  limit = 'LIMIT 1000',
  key = 'yourApiKey',
  //do you want a JSONP-response? Add a callback-parameter
  callback = '&callback=functionName',
  //prepare the query;
  sql = encodeURIComponent([columns, from, where, groupby, orderby, limit].join(' ')),
  //prepare the url
  url = [base, '?sql=', sql, callback, '&key=', key].join('');

//see what we got
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(url));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Monospace
}
```

Demo using all 4 clauses: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/fc47243g/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/fc47243g/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this completely makes the query work, but you're missing some spaces where you had `+`:

```
var base         = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?',
    columns      = 'sql=SELECT Lat,Lng,Date,Username,TripID ',
    from         = '+from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ',
    sort_factors = '+LIMIT 1000 AND ORDER BY Date DESC ',
    key          = '&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
```

Comment: he want's to create a URL, a `+` is a valid urlencoded space